# Always show a DIV as soon as its not visible any more after scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an info box (div) on my screen when the user opens my website. As soon as the user scrolls down and the box is not visible to the user any longer, I want the box to appear in the top right corner all the time while scrolling.

I know how to make it visible all the time (position: fixed). The problem is, how do I know when its not visible to the user ans more while scrolling? I can also use JavaScript, if that helps. Id prefer Prototype JS.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the scrollTop property you can determine whether the position should be fixed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of `getBoundingClientRect()`, which returns the element's positions relative to the viewport. If the `top` value is below `0`, then it should be fixed.

HTML:

```
<div id="stick">
    I should be fixed… sometimes
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#stick {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
}

#stick.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
var stick = document.getElementById('stick');

window.onscroll = function(){
    if(stick.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0){
        stick.className = 'fixed';
    } else if(stick.className.indexOf('fixed') < 0){
        stick.className = '';
    }
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/w9EgE/).